# @Viewscope not working with @Scope(value=BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) in bean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsf

I have a controller which is annotated with

`@Component(value = "somevalue")
@ViewScoped` everything was working fine but i had a lazyModel class which was singleton so i annotated with `@Scope(value=org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`

later i came to know @Autowire will give the same class for each request,so we need to get the class from context here is my controller...`@Component(value = "someValue")

```
@ViewScoped
public class ACAppUserController extends AbsController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeLazyModel lazyModel;

    public SomeLazyModel getLazyModel() {
        this.lazyModel = (SomeLazyModel) context.getBean("SomeLazyModel");
        return lazyModel;
    }

    public void setLazyModel(ACAppUserLazyModel lazyModel) {
        this.lazyModel = lazyModel;
    }

}
```

And here is my SomeLazyModel which have userModel...

```
@Component(value = "SomeLazyModel")
@Scope(value=org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class SomeLazyModel extends AbsSomeLazyModelLazyModel<UserModel> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(SomeLazyModel.class);


    private UserModel user;
```

Usermodel is having username,password variables...

> So my issue is When i submit the form username and password is null in
>   usermodel...

so before getting someLazyModel from context everything was working fine...

please do help on this...

Comment: What has JSF got to do with it? I see java code and only spring annotations... Nothing JSF related in here

Comment: Neither Spring MVC related.